# Xamarin forms Android app verison goes blackscreen randomly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I got this app im been working on i xamarin forms. where i use a ContantPages inside a navigationspage. like shown below

> MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SwipePage());

Now when i navigate to a other page like shown below, sometimes the screen goes black. If i then tap out of the app, and then tap in the app, the black screen will disappear, an the page content would be showing. making the app normally again.

> this.Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilPage());

I been trying to see if it's curse i load more data en app start, then resume. but i don't. its getting the same amount of load on resume, as on start.

So do anyone have a idea what it can be, or have tried something similar before?

Thanks for your time,

---UPDATE---

So In a emulator it runs without problems. but when i use a android device IRL it's keep doing that black screen thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is occurring because you are not awaiting the async method thus showing a black screen as the page is still rendering but you have already been pushed to the page.

Try using the await operator.

```
var page = new SwipePage();
await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

Comment: Funny thing is, that is working for WinPhone And IOS,
But yeah i been thinking that it could be something like that, but if i try to await it i get this error. And if i do that wouldn't that block the UI Thread?
**The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.**

Comment: And beside that, the first page it's happened on doesn't do anything else the rending some buttons. and it works on other pages where i actually call some web Api's

Comment: Hmm strange, To fix the await error just add an async type to the method, it wont block up the UI thread. The navigation examples on the Xamarin website are used in this manner. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/  

private async void LoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I made the event async and the await the push like you said. but nothing changes. still same result.